# OpenVpn - Curl works but browser doesnt

Tags: curl, browser, openvpn

UPDATE

When i connect my MacBook to the Internet via my iPhone, the VPN works flawlessly. But as soon as i use my KabelDeutschland Router it stops working. I guess it must have something to do with the Router.

END UPDATE

I am trying to connect to my corporate vpn network using OpenVpn. The connection is successfully established, i can also ping the IPs in the network, curl the webpages of the contained webservers, but when i try to use a browser like Firefox or Safari the same webpages which i curled successfully do not load or in some cases only very very slowly: in 5 minutes just the text is loaded, but no CSS is visible. In fact the browser does not instantly fail to connect, but tries for several minutes before timing out.

My config looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote some.server.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca ca.crt
cert mdata-sandbox-bjoern-new.crt
key mdata-sandbox-bjoern-new.key

remote-cert-tls server

comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Anybody got ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Btw: I tried to request the Webpages from at home using a Mac (from which i tried to ping and curl), a Windows computer and an Ubuntu within a VMware on the Windows machine. Results are all the same. Interestingly, i can use the browser to connect from my company network, but not from at home.

Comment: see the open ports of your site, make sure 80 is accessiable

Comment: In fact the ports which are used by the webapplications differ from 80. You mean, that port 80 should be open on the respective Servers containing the web apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is solved. The reason was that Kabel Deutschland only allowed IPv6 for my account. After changing to IPv4, everything worked flawlessly. Why curl, ping and wget did its Job is unclear to me. But at least, everything is working now. :)